# Android Studio: keep non-essential elements after revising application for release?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to software dev, so I don't know the proper etiquettes for this process.

I just want to keep certain debugging code (comments and stuff) and maybe some testing resources like images after cleaning an app for release. These are things the app will never need for functioning, just stuff I wanna keep.

Are comments kept after the compile? If not I can just comment out those lines.

I thought about using different flavours, but it doesn't seem appropriate? Just because the build release type makes 4 options.
-which I never really understood. Does switching from Debug mode to Release mode change anything code-wise? Like other than the signing methods and other discrete (discrete to me anyways) changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are comments kept after the compile? If not I can just comment out those lines.

Commented-out code isn't compiled, so if you want, yes you can comment out code and it won't show up in the final app. However, there's no way to comment out resources in the same way, so if there are resources you only want to have in your debug version, keep reading.

> I thought about using different flavours, but it doesn't seem
>   appropriate? Just because the build release type makes 4 options.

You're right, you don't need flavors because there's already build types (Debug and Release) which are set up to do what you want. Your Java code can tell the difference between debug and release types via the `BuildConfig` class, which is automatically generated as part of the build. It has a `DEBUG` Boolean constant that's defined to `true` for debug builds and `false` for release. So you can have code that does something like this:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    // Do something here that you don't want to have in the final release
}
```

Since `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is a `static final Boolean`, then Java is smart enough to see that what's inside that `if` block will never run in a release build, so the compiler will strip that code out and it won't appear in your app.

If there are resources you'd only like to have in the debug and not release versions of the app, then you can put them in a different folder in your hierarchy:

```
ProjectDirectory
+--app
   +--src
      +--main
         +--res  <--Your normal resources go here
         +--java
         +--AndroidManifest.xml
      +--debug
         +--res  <-- Put resources for the debug build only here
```

That debug/res folder won't be created by default, but if you set it up, the build system should pick it up. Having said that, debug-only resources are a little unusual; you would only have something like this if your debug version of the app had something like a diagnostic activity or menus or something like that. It's certainly possible, but it's a little more advanced than it sounds like what you're doing so far.

> -which I never really understood. Does switching from Debug mode to Release mode change anything code-wise? Like other than the signing
>   methods and other discrete (discrete to me anyways) changes?

Some of the important changes in a release build are:

- `BuildConfig.DEBUG` will be false as already noted.
- Your app will be signed with a release key instead of the debug key. The release key is what you will use to sign it to upload to the Google Play store. You'll need to set up that key if you don't have it already.
- Release apps are built as non-debuggable unless you change the setting.
- You can run ProGuard (which does dead code stripping and obfuscation) on release builds, though it's not configured to run by default.

Comment: Thanks so much! Buta just wondering, say I wanted to track onPause moments in debug, but not in release. The if-statement inside of the onPause method will strip out the Log.d, but what of the method, onResume(), itself? Assuming the release version has no need for one. Is this what ProGuard is for?

Comment: ProGuard isn't going to strip an empty `onResume()` method in this case. However, I wouldn't worry much about an empty method in the release version -- it will barely have any effect.